# Loop gets slower after each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop, time

I have a `python` scripts which is about the following:

1. I have a list of jsons
2. I create an empty `pandas` dataframe
3. I run a for loop on this list
4. I create an empty dictionary at every iteration with the (same) keys which are interesting for me
5. I parse the json at every iteration to retrieve the values of the keys
6. I append the dictionary at every iteration to the `pandas` dataframe

The issue with this is that at every iteration the processing time is increasing.
Specifically:

```
0-1000 documents -> 5 seconds
1000-2000 documents -> 6 seconds
2000-3000 documents -> 7 seconds
...
10000-11000 documents -> 18 seconds
11000-12000 documents -> 19 seconds
...
22000-23000 documents -> 39 seconds
23000-24000 documents -> 42 seconds
...
34000-35000 documents -> 69 seconds
35000-36000 documents -> 72 seconds
```

Why is this happening?

My code looks like this:

```
# 'documents' is the list of jsons

columns = ['column_1', 'column_2', ..., 'column_19', 'column_20']

df_documents = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for index, document in enumerate(documents):

    dict_document = dict.fromkeys(columns)

    ...
    (parsing the jsons and retrieve the values of the keys and assign them to the dictionary)
    ...

    df_documents = df_documents.append(dict_document, ignore_index=True)
```

**P.S.**

After applying @eumiro's suggestion below the times are the following:

```
    0-1000 documents -> 0.06 seconds
    1000-2000 documents -> 0.05 seconds
    2000-3000 documents -> 0.05 seconds
    ...
    10000-11000 documents -> 0.05 seconds
    11000-12000 documents -> 0.05 seconds
    ...
    22000-23000 documents -> 0.05 seconds
    23000-24000 documents -> 0.05 seconds
    ...
    34000-35000 documents -> 0.05 seconds
    35000-36000 documents -> 0.05 seconds
```

After applying @DariuszKrynicki's suggestion below the times are the following:

```
0-1000 documents -> 0.56 seconds
1000-2000 documents -> 0.54 seconds
2000-3000 documents -> 0.53 seconds
...
10000-11000 documents -> 0.51 seconds
11000-12000 documents -> 0.51 seconds
...
22000-23000 documents -> 0.51 seconds
23000-24000 documents -> 0.51 seconds
...
34000-35000 documents -> 0.51 seconds
35000-36000 documents -> 0.51 seconds
...
```

Comment: @JohnColeman, 1) it may sth other than the `...`, 2) if the `...` is quadratic then it won't be approximately the same at each iteration? Or if not the same the it would fluctuate every time (sometimes lower, sometimes higher)? But here as you see it only steadily increases.

Comment: It is because your df_documents is growing.

Comment: @JohnColeman, regarding my point (1) below, see the answers of other people below. (You left the battlefield by deleting your comment? haha)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `append`ing to a DataFrame will be slower after each new line, because it has to copy the whole (growing) content again and again.

Create a simple list, append to it and then create one DataFrame in one step:

```
records = []

for index, document in enumerate(documents):
    …
    records.append(dict_document)

df_documents = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
```

Comment: Why do not you use iterator or generator? You do not need to keep your list in memory all the time. You only need it once you want to access the data.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that 'append' was still so inefficient. I have tested it and the results are much much better (upvote). Check my edited post, thank you :)

Comment: @PoeteMaudit A DataFrame is efficient. Appending a new row is efficient too. Creating the whole DataFrame by appending each row separately cannot be efficient.

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki that's the level 2.

Comment: what if i do 3200 iterations in the loop over a long period of time? let's say each iteration takes about 15 seconds while scraping a page with selenium. if all fails nothing gets logged. each iteration have to save out to the csv file...

Answer (score 3):

The answer could already lie in the `pandas.DataFrame.append` method which you are constantly using. This is very inefficient, as it needs to allocate new memory frequently, i.e. copying the old one, which could explain your results. See also the official [pandas.DataFrame.append docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) for this:

> Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once.

with the two examples:

> Less efficient:
>
> ```
> >>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A'])
> >>> for i in range(5): ...     df = df.append({'A': i}, ignore_index=True)
> >>> df    A 0  0 1  1 2  2 3  3 4  4
> ```
>
> More efficient:
>
> ```
> >>> pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([i], columns=['A']) for i in range(5)], ...           ignore_index=True)    A 0  0 1  1 2  2 3  3 4  4
> ```

You can apply the same strategy, create a list of dataframes instead of appending to the same dataframe with each iteration, then `concat` once your `for` loop is finished

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your DataFrame is growing with each iteration.
How about using iterators?

```
# documents = # json
def get_df_from_json(document):
    columns = ['column_1', 'column_2', ..., 'column_19', 'column_20']
    # parsing the jsons and retrieve the values of the keys and assign them to the dictionary)
    # dict_document =  # use document to parse it and create dictionary
    return pd.DataFrame(list(dict_document.values()), index=dict_document)   

res = (get_df_from_json(document) for document in enumerate(documents))
res = pd.concat(res).reset_index()
```

EDIT:
I have made a quick comparison on such example as below and it turns out that iterator use does not speed up the code against list comprehension use:

```
import json
import time


def get_df_from_json():
    dd = {'a': [1, 1], 'b': [2, 2]}
    app_json = json.dumps(dd)
    return pd.DataFrame(list(dd.values()), index=dd)

start = time.time()
res = pd.concat((get_df_from_json() for x in range(1,20000))).reset_index()
print(time.time() - start)


start = time.time()
res = pd.concat([get_df_from_json() for x in range(1,20000)]).reset_index()
print(time.time() - start)
```

iterator: 9.425999879837036
list comprehension: 8.934999942779541

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer too - it looks interesting (upvote). How much faster do you think it will be that 0.05s per 1000 documents? I will test it and see but to start with what is `dd` at your code?

Comment: dd is my shortcut from dictionary. I have update my answer to refer to dict_document. Using iterator will make your code efficient from memory usage perspective. I strongly advice to look into iterators and generators in python. They may look complicated at first glance but are simple in its base concepts and easy to use.

Comment: Yes, I have them in mind but I am have not used them extensively. Let's see if it faster though to start with and by how much.

Comment: Hey, I get this `TypeError: get_df_from_json() missing 1 required positional argument: 'document'`. Am I missing or you are missing something? Probably `res = (get_df_from_json(document) for document in enumerate(documents))`?

Comment: Hey, see the times at my edited post. It is quite slower actually than eumiro's solution. (unless I am missing sth)